# how can I access the second _id from the mongoDb document?

Tags: javascript

How can I access the second ID from here?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. Don't show code or data as images.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
db.collection.find({job: {_id: theIdYouWantToAccess }})
```

There's more info in the MongoDB documentation, depending on what you want to do.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-embedded-documents